# PHP Date from Webhook

Tags: php, sms, webhooks

I can't seem to figure out how to format the webhook variable.  This is an SMS and it's texting Wed Dec 31st 1969 @ 7:00 PM as the date every time.  I can't seem to work out getting the webhook variable to be formatted.

The webhook variable for the date is old_date

$date=date('D M j @ g:i A', strtotime($old_date));

$content = "Hi ".$_POST[name]." this is a reminder that we have a meeting scheduled at ".$date."";//content of the SMS

Tried this way...

$date=date('D M j Y @ g:i A', strtotime($_POST['old_date']));

$content = "Hi ".$_POST[name]." this is a reminder that we have a meeting scheduled at ".$date."";//content of the SMS

And that way...

$date=date('D M j Y @ g:i A', strtotime($_POST[old_date]));

$content = "Hi ".$_POST[name]." this is a reminder that we have a meeting scheduled at ".$date."";//content of the SMS

The last two ways failed to send an SMS.

Comment: I'm trying to reword the question here because the link to that last post didn't help me.  I can't get the format to the webhook variable to be formatted.  I can change the format itself.  But for some reason can't figure out how to get the webhook date to format.  It's either the date as the webhook's original format or the date I mentioned above.

Comment: I'm new here.  sorry.  For some reason it wouldn't let me.  Probably user error.

Comment: The $date variable isn't a date that strtotime can parse. You need to use createfromformat http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm missing here but it doesn't show a date.  $Ndate = $_POST[old_date];
$format = 'Y-m-d';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $Ndate);

$content = "Hi ".$_POST[name]." this is a reminder that we have a meeting scheduled at ".$date."";//content of the SMS

Comment: $date = DateTime::createFromFormat(Y-m-d, $_POST['old_date']);

$content = "Hi ".$_POST[name]." this is a reminder that we have a meeting scheduled at $date";//content of the SMS

Comment: Still not working.  No output for the date/time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's a webhook should `$old_date` be loaded from
one of those variables ?
 `$_POST['old_date']   $_GET['old_date']   $_REQUEST['old_date']`  ?

It's not clear to me how you set $old_date

I think it's returning Dec31 1969 which means $old_date is null or zero

Try adding year to do further testing

```
$date=date('Y, D M j @ g:i A', strtotime($old_date));
```

Comment: Yes, 1969 

$Ndate = $_POST['old_date'];
$date=date('D M j Y @ g:i A', strtotime($Ndate));

$content = "Hi ".$_POST[name]." this is a reminder that we have a meeting scheduled at ".$date."";//content of the SMS

Comment: I also tried this way which didn't work either. $date=date('D M j Y @ g:i A', strtotime($_POST['old_date']));

$content = "Hi ".$_POST[name]." this is a reminder that we have a meeting scheduled at ".$date."";//content of the SMS

Comment: Try this $content = json_encode($_REQUEST);  Will give you more insight of what data the webhook is sending you

Comment: This is the URL for the webhook https://www.sicklehunter.com/sendsms.php?name=${Clients.First Name}&number=${Clients.Mobile}&old_date=${Events.From}&SMS=<SMS>

Comment: maybe strtotime is unable to convert string to a date ( non-standard date format ), so try sending the actual old_date value instead of reformatting it.  try $content = "Hi ".$_POST[name]." ".$_GET['old_date'];

Comment: Please post the string that comes "old_date" before formatting

Comment: I think that's where my confusion is.  I'm not sure how to define the webhook variable so it can be formatted.

Comment: This returns nothing for the date. $formatteddate = $_POST[old_date];
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat(Y-m-d,$formatteddate);

$content = "Hi ".$_POST[name]." this is a reminder that we have a meeting scheduled at $date";//content of the SMS

Comment: To help you I need to know the actual format of old_date, which until now I don't know how it's content look like. without knowing how old_date originally looks like I won't be able to help you formatting it

Comment: 04-01-2017 01:00:00 P

Comment: I have another date field that produces this 1491069600000

Comment: The second one "1491069600000" is time in milliseconds and can be easily used  $timestamp= 1491063186541/ 1000;  Divide by thousand to get seconds , then $date=date('D M j Y @ g:i A',$timestamp);

Comment: Worked.  I finished it will this $ndate=$_POST['old_date'];
$timestamp= $ndate/ 1000; 
$date=date('D M j @ g:i A',$timestamp);
Thank you.